# how to compare distinct implementations of java.security.cert.X509Certificate

Tags: java, bouncycastle, x509, pki

I'm using bouncycastle org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject and sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl in different parts of my app, and sometimes I need to compare them for equality, equals() method is not working and methods like getSubjectDN().getName() display different results for each of these implementations, how could I compare these certificates for equality without going to binary DER or PEM comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A safe way to tell if two certificates are equal is to compare their binary representation. Both the Bouncy Castle and Sun's implementation feature a `getEncoded` method. You could compare the two with Arrays#equals.

You should avoid comparing SubjectDN or IssuerDN strings, it is quite possible that the representation differs even if on the binary level they are perfectly equal. I had to learn this the hard way when interfacing with .NET - the naming of the individual relative distinguished names (such as CN, O, OU...) was different for more exotic RDNs. My advice would be to stay on the binary level for comparison, tricky high-level comparisons are error-prone and harder to maintain.

Comment: it was my error to tell that equals() wasn't working  I was getting wrong references when comparing, equals() work, and it uses binary comparison as you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: I think that the chances are one in a gazillion that they would match... I did not want to go encoded, but seems quite trustful. Gonna give it a try.

Comment: @NoProblemBabe It works more often than one might think ;) No, but honestly, underneath it's all DER-encoded X.509 certificates, if implemented correctly, there's no room for ambiguity, regardless of the library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to compare using MD5 or SHA-1 hashes of the certificate data.  This is how the certificate fingerprint is generated, and would give you assurances of the equality of the two.

Comment: But can't that take more time than the byte[] comparison? Not trying to be an arse or anything... just asking...

Comment: But is a very clever way of compare, i'll give ya that

Comment: @NoProblemBabe If only done once it takes longer and wouldn't give you any benefit over comparing the bytes directly. But it can be very useful if you happen to compare lots of certificates many, many times. Then, the initial cost for creating the hash will be outweighed by the fact that you only need to compare 20 bytes (SHA-1) instead of potentially thousands for the whole certificate.

Comment: If you're concerned about the overhead of generating a SHA-1 hash, then you could validate both of the certificates (to ensure they haven't been tampered with) and then grab the byte[] signatures of bot and compare.  At the end of the day it's very similar to performing a SHA-1 hash and comparing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the certificate in this case client (BouncyCastle) to java.security

```
try {
            byte[] encoded = client.getEncoded();
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(encoded);
            java.security.cert.CertificateFactory cf = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            x509CertificateC = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
        } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException e) {
        } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
        }
```